# How to compose expectations in testthat?

Tags: r, testthat

A naive approach to writing custom expectations from existing expectations is:

```
expect_between <- function (x, lo, hi) {
    expect_lte(lo, x)
    expect_lte(x, hi)
}
```

but this doesn't work with `expect_failure`, since `expect_failure` captures the first expectation.

```
expect_between(0.5, 0, 1)                  # PASSES
expect_between(-99, 0, 1)                  # FAILS
expect_between(99, 0, 1)                   # FAILS
expect_failure(expect_between(-99, 0, 1))  # PASSES
expect_failure(expect_between(99, 0, 1))   # FAILS <--- the problem
```

What is the proper way to compose expectations when writing user-defined expectations, so that they still play well with `expect_failure`?

Comment: Can you give a more clear example of what's not working with expect_failure?

Comment: @MrFlick Done, thanks for the suggestion.